FlutterFlow firebase push notifications by API call failed, error code400 and "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token"
POST return 400 error message: "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project_id/messages:send
Headers: "Authorization": "Bearer $accesstoken
Body: {
{
  "message": {
    "token": "FCMtoken",
    "notification": {
      "title": "acb",
      "body": "FF hello"
    }
  }
}

my flutterFlow setting, custom backend without auth using firebase, have enabled push notifications  connecting with firebase.
use custom code to get FCM token successfully.
I try many way to generate access token(gcloud, node), still not working,please guide me how to fixed it, thank you so much everyone.
